# IF ELSE Statement in python selenium webdriver not executing Else when element is not there

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am using an automation script with selenium web driver. It usually works fine, but sometimes the content on a page is changing.

If the element it is looking for is not there, it is crashing instead of executing the else statement.

I Tried to use another function with try and NoSuchElementException, but I do get another error about NoSuchElementException.

This is the if else statement:

```
#Look for link text "Stores"
find_store = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Stores')
if find_store:
    find_store.click()
else:
    driver.get("https://example.com/myaccount")
time.sleep(5)
```

This is the try statement:

```
try:
    find_store = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Stores')
    if find_store.is_displayed():
        find_store.click() # this will click the element if it is there
        print("Store found, all good.")
except NoSuchElementException:
    driver.get("https://example.com/myaccount")
    print("Store was not found, visiting base URL to search for store")
time.slep(5)
```

In the first script I expect it to search for the element. If its not there, then visit the URL so I can search for the element there. But it never opens the URL and I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

In the second script I expect to look for the element. If the element is not there, it should visit the base url and try again later in the code. However here I get this error:

```
  except NoSuchElementException:
NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined
```

I would like to learn how I can avoid the script crashing and actually execute an alternative action if the element is not there. Thank you.

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` is not a globally defined name. You have to import it before you can use it: `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Following :**

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Stores'))> 0:
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Stores').click()
else:
    driver.get("https://example.com/myaccount")
time.sleep(5)
```